# How to lock y axis movement in achartengine bar chart?

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I'd like to use achartengine for my development. I'm using achartengine. But I want my bar chart not move along y axis. In default we can move the chart along x and y axis. But I just want to making movement in x axis only. How can I do it?? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 15):

Use `renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);` in order to get that behavior.

If you want to lock both axis, then use `renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);`